# Change Woocommerce order status based on payment gateway and transition status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

So I know how to change status based on payment gateway. But is there a way to also take the previous order status into account?

My issue is as following: we start processing our orders after the customer sign an e-contract. They are then free to pay later via a couple gateways (Stripe, COD, bank transfer or invoice - we send payment links).

This means that customers can pay during any of our order statuses (from pending, awaiting signature to processing-unpaid, delivery-unpaid, completed ect).

We also have 'Paid' versions of these statuses: processing-paid, delivery-paid etc.

So for example: payment gateway Stripe triggers status 'Processing-paid'. That's fine if the previous status was 'Processing-unpaid'. However, if we're further along the process, after we already have delivered, say, it should ideally change from 'Delivery-unpaid to 'Completed'.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this done. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'woo_order_status_change_custom', 10, 3);] methinks, and $order->status to get the current status, than manually set it in the hook, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson ! Sorry, no not really. I'm not that good at coding (I'm a marketeer, not really a developer). I'm more of a copy/paste and experiment until it works kinda girl. Would you be willing to be a little more specific?

Comment: Sorry for the no reply @Florence, I went away for the rest of the weekend (yay!). Saved by Loic once again.....

Comment: @GavinSimpson No worries! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using [`woocommerce_order_status_changed`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#334) hook where you can target your orders statuses transition **"from"** and **"to"**, to change the order status to any other.

In this example I target the statuses **"from"** **`delivery-unpaid`** and **"to"** **`delivery-paid`** to change the order status to `completed`.

As you can see in Woocommerce the Order statuses are slugs *(all in lowercase)*…

You can target, at the same time, a **specific payment gateway ID** like **Stripe** using something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'change_order_status_conditionally', 10, 4 );
function change_order_status_conditionally( $order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order ) {
    if( $order->get_payment_method() === 'stripe' && $status_from === 'delivery-unpaid' && $status_to === 'delivery-paid' ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

As you can see you can add as many `IF` statements targeting the order statuses transitions that you need to change it to any other status and payment gateways.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: So I just tried this and I can't believe how easy that was! Thank you so much! I am noticing a minor inconvenience though. The old status transition ( from > to) is shown in the order notes. The note appears after the new (correct) order transition note as well. Strange!

Comment: @FlorenceGielen On order update status, an admin order note is always generated.

Comment: Okay. I made it work by making all payments cycle through a payment-received status, so those notes will make sense to the store owners. Thanks again :)